# automatically spot the difference - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe that has hundreds of columns and thousands of rows. I'm running a test that adds a new column onto the dataframe and it's supposed to match one of the others.

```
df['test_A'] = ... some computation depending on other columns ...
assert all(df['test_A'] == df['A'])
```

The assert statement fails because a small percentage of the rows do not match, less than 1 percent. Let's call them 1p rows for ease.

I want to know what the difference is between these particular rows and all the others. For instance, perhaps the 1p rows have a column ('B') which are all False, or within a specific numeric range or something like that.

This is more of a basic ML question because there should be a package or method or technique that shows the uniqueness of these rows compared to all the others. What can I use to automatically spot the difference?

## EDIT - example

Allow me to give a small example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'B': [100, 100, 103, 10, 106], 
    'C': [False, True, False, False, True]})

def whats_unique_about_these_rows(df, index):
    '''
    return what is special about these rows
    compared to the rest of the rows in the dataframe
    '''
    # return magic

whats_unique_about_these_rows(df, 3)
>> {
>>    'A': '>2 & <4',
>>    'B': '<100',
>>    'C': 'no unique value'}
```

As I've described this in greater detail now with this example I think what I'm asking for is a miniature decision tree on all the columns. Like, what are the boundaries that describe this data compared to the rest of the data?

Could I just use scikit-learn's decision tree algorithm or something?

Comment: This isn't a "Machine Learning" question, but a data mungling/wrangling question. Can you add some example data?

Comment: Try ```print(df[df['test_A'] != df['A']])```

Comment: @JoãoVictor I think you've missed the point, let me add an example to the question.

Comment: @Erfan I've added the example, hoping that helps